# __cplusplus macro to tell g++ about C header declarations not working strangely

Tags: c++, c, g++

I have a mix of C C++ code. All compiled with g++. Wherever I have C headers I have the contents of the header file included inside

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
extern "C" {
#endif
```

and

```
#if defined(__cplusplus)
    extern "C" {
    #endif
```

But in one C header file I get g++ compilation errors where I have accidentally used a parameter name as template , which obviously is incorrect and in conflict with c++ keyword **template**.

I know I can go and change this parameter name, but I am thinking why is this `extern "C"` declaration not working and why is the header file considered as C++ code and not C as I intended to.

g++ version 4.1.1 Linux Red Hat Enterprise.

Comment: @Griwes - I know. But legacy code, legacy builds. Changes are slow!

Comment: @Griwes, I still use 3.x sometimes :)

Comment: @AmigableClarkKant, which doesn't change the *fact* that 4.1.1 is **OLD**.

Comment: @Griwes, haha, no. It's to do with age also I think. It feels like yesterday switching from 2.95

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `extern "C"` only tells the compiler <del>(actually, the linker)</del> that C++ name mangling doesn't apply to the functions declared in that scope. It has nothing to do with the syntax or keywords themselves.

Your best solution is to rename the conflicting symbols.

Comment: IS that so. I was thinking. extern "C" tells the linker that the following declarations are C code. Which even the C++ faq http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html#faq-32.3  seemed to say.

Comment: @goldenmean yes, and there's no contradiction here. It tells it they are C functions because C functions don't have C++ name mangling...

Comment: Luchian is correct. See also [Raymond Chen](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2012/05/25/10310148.aspx).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Actually it tells the *compiler*, not *linker*. Name mangling is a job of compiler, not linker.

Comment: @Nawaz but the linker actually looks for the symbols.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yup. But that lookup has nothing to with `extern "C"`. All that it needs the symbol and where to look for it.

Comment: @Thanks Lucian, Nawaz, Raymond.

Answer (score 4):

Consider:

```
extern "C" {
  namespace n
  {
    int& foo(bool b)
    {
      if (!b)
        throw std::invalid_argument("fail!");
      static int i = 0;
      return ++i;
    }
  }
}
```

This function has C language linkage, but uses references, namespaces and exceptions, which I hope demonstrates that `extern "C"` doesn't magically switch the compiler to compiling C, it just tells the compiler to use C calling conventions and symbol-naming conventions for the functions and variables with C language linkage (which usually just means it disables name-mangling and causes matching declarations in different namespaces to refer to the same entity.)

Comment: Thanks Really. By giving a 'counter example' if I may call it so, i.e. C++ code syntax inside a extern C linkage, it clears my concept nicely.